# Degree of the composition

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to prove that if $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is a homeomorphism, $f(1)=1$ then $deg(f)= \pm1$.

I noticed that if it holds that $deg([g \circ h])=deg([g]) \cdot deg([h]) (*)$ then the claim follows easily, but I'm not sure if $(*)$ holds and if it does how to prove it. I found some similar posts and they were using the fact $(g \circ h)_*=g_* \circ h_*$ but I'm not sure if this helps with the definition I am using for a degree or how to use it in order to prove $(*)$.

The definition of the degree is the following: For a closed path $\alpha: I=[0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ there is a unique lift $\alpha'$ for which $\alpha'(0)=0$ then $deg(\alpha)=\alpha'(1)$. Then, for $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$  define $deg(f)=deg(f \circ p)$ where $p:I \rightarrow S^1$ with $p(t)=e^{i2 \pi t}$

I also know that $deg:\pi_1(S^1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a group isomorphism, where on the LHS is the fundamental group of $S^1$ where the operation is $[f_1] \cdot [f_2]=[f_1*f_2]$ where $*$ represents the concatenation of paths $f_1,f_2:I \rightarrow S^1$

(Notation follows Rotman's book:'An introduction to Algebraic Topology')

Edit: The comments suggest that $(*)$ holds , but I'm still not sure how to prove it.

Comment: $\ast$ holds and is the way to show this fact.

Comment: $\deg(f)$ is the image of $1 \in \Bbb Z$ in the induced map $f_\ast: H^1(S^1) \to H^1(S^1) \simeq \Bbb Z$. This determines $f_\ast$ completely.

Comment: That fact plus $(g \circ h)_\ast = g_\ast \circ h_\ast$ does the rest.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Is $H^1(S^1)$ the fundamental group of $S^1$? And why $deg(f)$ is the image of $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ in $f_*$? The theorem I know that holds true regarding deg is: $deg: \pi_1(S^1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a group isomorphism where on the left is the fundamental group of $S^1$

Comment: Yes I meant $\pi_1(S^1,1)$ in fact. The first homotopy (or homology) group. Which happen to be the same here.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm still not sure as to why $deg(f)$ is the image of $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ in $f_*$

Comment: I think it follows from the unique lifting

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Can you write the exact statement that you mean when you say that $deg(f)$ is the image of $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$? Because $f_*:\pi_1(S^1,1) \rightarrow \pi_1(S^1,1)$ with $f_*([g])=[f \circ g]$ and $deg:\pi_1(S^1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: $f_\ast(1)$ is a member of $\Bbb Z$ where $1$ is the homotooy class of the identity as a generating member of $\pi_1(S^1, 1)$. Its image under $f_\ast$ is homotopic to some $ z^k: S^1\to S^1$. This $k$ is the degree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you speak about a *lift* of a path, it seems that you know the covering projection $\exp: \mathbb R \to S^1, \exp(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$. However, you should mention that you only consider maps $f : S^1 \to S^1$ such that $f(1) = 1$ (basepoint preserving maps). This assures that $\alpha_f = f \circ p$ has a lift  $\alpha'_f$ which maps $0$ to $0$. We have $\alpha'_f(1) \in \mathbb Z$.

1. solution:

If $f$ is a homeomorphism, then it maps $U  = S^1 \setminus \{1\}$ homeomorphically onto itself. Moreover $p$ maps $(0,1)$ homeomorphically onto $U$, and therefore $\alpha_f$ does the same. $U$ is evenly covered with sheets $V_k = (k,k+1)$, $k\in \mathbb Z$. Since $\alpha'_f((0,1))$ is a connected subset of $\exp^{-1}(U)$, it must be contained in some $V_k$. But $e_k : V_k \stackrel{\exp}{\to} U$ is a homeomorphism such that $e_k \circ \alpha'_f \mid_{(0,1)} =  \alpha_f \mid_{(0,1)}$. Hence $\alpha'_f \mid_{(0,1)} : (0,1) \to V_k$ is a homeomorphism. Since $\alpha'_f(0) = 0$, we must have $k = 0$ or $k=-1$. But then clearly $\alpha'_f(1) = 1$ if $k = 0$ and $\alpha'_f(1) = -1$ if $k = -1$. Thus $\deg f = \pm 1$.

2. solution:

We know that $\deg : \pi_1(S^1,1) \to \mathbb Z$ is a group isomorphism. The homotopy class $\deg^{-1}(n)$ is represented by $\mu_n : S^1 \to S^1, \mu_n(z) = z^n$. Let $f, g : S^1 \to S^1$ with $\deg f = n $ and $\deg g = m$. Then
$$[f \circ g] = [f] \circ [g] = [\mu_n] \circ [\mu_m] =  [\mu_n \circ \mu_m] = [\mu_{n\cdot m}]$$
because $(\mu_n \circ \mu_m)(z) = \mu_n(\mu_m(z)) = \mu_n(z^m) = (z^m)^n = z^{n\cdot m} = \mu_{n\cdot m}(z)$. We conclude
$$\deg([f \circ g]) = \deg([f] \circ [g]) = \deg \mu_{n\cdot m} = n \cdot m = \deg [f] \cdot \deg [g] $$
which suffices to prove your claim.

Comment: I'm still processing your answer, but I'm not sure about the second solution because in the fundamental group $\pi_1(S^1,1)$ the operation is $[f_1] \cdot [f_2]=[f_1*f_2]$ where * is the concatenation and I'm interested in the $deg([f_1 \circ f_2])$

Comment: @WalterWhite $f \circ g$ denotes the composition $S^1 \stackrel{g}{\to} S^1  \stackrel{f}{\to} S^1$. I computed the degree of this composed map. If $f$ is a homeomorphism with inverse $f^{-1}$, then $1 = \deg id = \deg (f \circ f^{-1}) = \deg f \cdot \deg f^{-1} $. This is only possible if $\deg f =\pm 1 $.

Comment: What I mean is that for example I dont see why the equality $[\mu_n] \circ [\mu_m]=[\mu_n \circ \mu_m]$  holds. Instead, the equality that holds is $[\mu_n] \cdot [\mu_m]=[\mu_n * \mu_m]$ where * is the concatenation of paths and $\cdot$ is the operation in $\pi_1(S_1,1)$(unless I  understood something wrong)

Comment: @WalterWhite If we have maps $\phi, \phi' :A \to B, \psi, \psi' :B \to C$, then if $\phi \simeq \phi'$ and $\psi \simeq \psi'$ we get $[\psi  \circ \phi] = [\psi' \circ \phi']$. Thus  $[\psi] \circ [\phi] = [\psi \circ \phi]$ is well-defined, and that is what I used in my proof. Your equation is of course also true, but it only says that $\deg : \pi_1(S^1,1) \to \mathbb Z$ is a group homomorphism which we already know. Note that the operation $([f],[g]) \mapsto [f \circ g]$ has nothing to do with the group multiplication in $\pi_1(S^1,1) $.

Comment: You can also directly argue that $f \simeq \mu_n$ and $g \simeq \mu_m$ implies $f \circ g \simeq \mu_n \circ \mu_m$.

Comment: I think I got it, that's where I was confused all along. Thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 2):

I would mention the things that I think would give the above result without looking for the fact that $\deg$ is multiplicative.

let us suppose that $S^{1}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Also it is easy to see that $S^{1}$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R /  \Bbb Z$. with the homeomorphism defined by :
$$  g : \Bbb R / \Bbb Z \rightarrow S^{1} \\
     g([t]) = e^{2\pi i t}\\
$$
with this homeomorphism, one easily sees that every closed loop can be interpreted as a map from $S^1 \text{ to } S^{1}$. And vice versa.

On the other hand, there is a notion of covering space. A covering space for a topological space $X$ is a triple $(E,p, F)$. Where $F$ is a discrete topological space and p is a continuous map from $E$ to $X$ s.t. for all $x$ in $X$, there exists a $U \subset X$ open and $x \in U$ such that $p^{-1}(U) \simeq U \times F$. A lift always is defined with respect to a covering in a way that it always commutes with the initial map via the covering map($p$). So in our case, $E =\Bbb R$ and $p : \Bbb R \rightarrow S^{1}$ with
$p(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$ and $F$ is $\Bbb Z$. Now for a closed path $\gamma$,$\gamma(1) = 1$, let $\tilde{\gamma}$ be its lift. then $\deg(\gamma):= \tilde{\gamma}(1) - \tilde{\gamma}(0)$. it is clear that the degree is an integer and can be seen that it is independent of the lift of $\gamma$. Now for a map $f : S^{1} \to S^{1}$ the degree defined above is the degree of the map as a closed path defined from $[0,1]$. In our case case $f$ is homeomorphsism so the degree of $f$ as a closed path must be $\pm 1 $, other wise every point of $S^{1}$ would have more than $1$ inverse image.